# Apache with PHP 5.3 in 2021

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to install **PHP 5.3 and an Apache webserver on Ubuntu 20.04**. I know that PHP 5.3 is very old, but i need it temporary while i'm upgrading the Website to a new PHP Version.

I have tried multiple ways.

Installed Apache via repo and PHP with binaries multiple times. (with different switches like --with-apxs2, --enable-so)
I also tried to install Apache from binaries as well.
But every time the PHP code was sent as comment to the client. The PHP module was activated.

I don't find anything on the web anymore. Is it even possible to install on a new system like ubuntu 20.04

Do you know where I can find a step by step Instruction for installing PHP 5.3 in 2021 ^^
Or am I missing out something obvious.

Thank you for your help

Comment: May be you can use older Ubuntu version such 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Slava Rozhnev. I tried the installation with Ubuntu 14.04 and followed this guide : https://gist.github.com/arbabnazar/edf23236f33e1f5c052b6444ef6cebe0

And it worked ^^